# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors for time-periodic differential operator

Tags: matrices, partial-differential-equations, matrix-equations, differential, differential-operators

I'm trying to solve and simplify a bigger equation, for this purpose I  want to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this differential operator:
$$
( A(t) - \frac{d}{dt} )
$$
***where A(t) is T-periodic matrix***

I can't find a way to find the eigenvalues $q_\beta$ and eigenvectors $v_\beta(t)$ of the equation
$$
( A(t) - \frac{d}{dt} ) v_\beta = q_\beta v_\beta
$$

my guess is that  $v_\beta$ is also $T$-periodic column vectors.

What do you think?